# Is it possible to analytically find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the following matrix?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mathematics, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

$M$ is a $R \times R$ dimensional square matrix. The elements of $M$ are
\begin{align}
[M]_{nm} &= R \hspace{3 cm} when \hspace{.2 cm} n=m, \\
       &= \frac{1-e^\frac{2\pi i R (n-m)}{f}}{1-e^\frac{2\pi i  (n-m)}{f}} \hspace{1 cm} when \hspace{.2 cm} n \neq m ,
\end{align}
where $n$, $m$ are row and column indices respectively and $f$ is a mixed fraction not larger than $R+1$. Is it possible to analytically find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $M$?

Comment: This question is about math, not physics, and belongs on [math.se].

Comment: It looks like a circulant matrix. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix. These matrices have very nice diagonalization properties

Comment: Interesting. Thanks.

Comment: @AbuSalehMusa sorry, my bad. It is not actually a circulant matrix.

Comment: @Diego I think they are related. It's a Toeplitz matrix, at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really an answer, more of a trail-map. Your Toeplitz matrix is also manifestly hermitian, so
$$
M= R~{\mathbb I} +N,
$$
for hermitian traceless *N* which determines all real eigenvalues and eigenvectors shifted by the trivial *R*.

For *R* =2,  define $z\equiv \exp (-\pi i/f)$, so
$$
N=(z+z^*) \begin{bmatrix} 0 & z\\  z^* &0  \end{bmatrix},
$$
with eigenvalues $\pm 2\cos(\pi/f)$, for eigenvectors $(1,z^*)^T$ and
$(1,z)^T$, respectively. So the eigenvalues of *M* are just $2 \pm 2\cos(\pi/f)$.

I should not spoil the fun of carrying out the *R* = 3 for you,
$$ N=  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1+z^2+z^4& 1+z^4+z^8\\ \hbox{h.c.}&0&    1+z^2+z^4\\
\hbox{h.c.} & \hbox{ h.c.}&0 \end{bmatrix},
$$
which has a tasteful Gegenbauer structure...